# SQLXML Bulkload - how to pass a FK value to a relation - composite key

Tags: sql, xml, xsd

I am manually creating an XSD file to import to MS SQL using the SQLXML Bulkload library.

I am setting up relationships in the annotation and would like to pass the primary key of the Parent table to the Child table as a foreign key. Is there away to do this without having the FK data already existing in the child data in the XML?

XML

```
<ParentExample projectId="testprojectId" serialNumber="XXXXXXX"/>
<ChildExample  randomstuff="random">
```

XSD

```
<xsd:appinfo>  
<sql:relationship name="ParenttoChild"  
      parent="ParentExample"  
      parent-key="projectId serialNumber"  
      child="ChildExample"  
      child-key="projectId serialNumber" /></xsd:appinfo>...

      <xsd:element name="ParentExample" sql:relation="ParentExample" 
       maxOccurs="unbounded">
           <xsd:complexType>
               <xsd:attribute name="projectId" type="xsd:string" />
               <xsd:attribute name="serialNumber" type="xsd:string" />
           </xsd:complexType>
       </xsd:element>
      <xsd:element name="ChildExample" sql:relation="ChildExample" 
       maxOccurs="unbounded" sql:relationship="ParenttoChild">
           <xsd:complexType>
               <xsd:attribute name="projectId" type="xsd:string" />
               <xsd:attribute name="serialNumber" type="xsd:string" />
               <xsd:attribute name="randomstuff" type="xsd:string" />
           </xsd:complexType>
       </xsd:element>
```

Currently the result is that the projectId and serialNumber fields show up in the DB for the Child table, but the are not populating from the Parent. The data is null in the child table for the two foreign keys. Thank you for any help!  Is there a way to populate the child table from the parent through the XSD?